# Common Lisp: asdf depends-on specific version

Tags: common-lisp, dependency-management, quicklisp, asdf

I'd like to know how to depend on a specific version of a library in a ASDF system?

```
(asdf:defsystem #:my-system
    :serial t
    :description "Describe my-system here"
    :author "My Name <my.name@example.com>"
    :license "Specify license here"
    :depends-on (#:hunchentoot
                 #:cl-who)
    :components ((:file "package")
                 (:file "dispatch")))
```

The above system depends on hunchentoot and cl-who. As of my understanding the latest versions of both libraries will be used. How can I specify to use cl-who 1.0.5 (e.g) instead?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
:depends-on ((:version #:hunchentoot "1.2.18")
             #:cl-who)
```

Note, that in current `ASDF` (version 3.1) that will be treated as version 1.2.18+ .

Answer (score 1):

The :version declarations in your ASDF systems can be used to enable ASDF to check that things are good.

If you want to control what versions are loaded then you need to control what ASDF finds when it searches for the systems.

If you want Quicklisp to download and install particular systems then you need to understand how Quicklisp distributions are setup.

Comment: You mean even if I depend on version 1.2.18 and asdf finds version 1.2.24 it will still load it? How do I tell quicklisp and asdf then to download and use version 1.2.18?

Comment: You can configure where and in what order ASDF searches for systems.  So if you have the one you desire where it get's found first you'll be happy.   The Quicklisp team (sic) releases distributions, i.e. the entire set of projects with specific versions from time to time.  It maybe you prefer an older release and you can set your quicklisp configuration to use an older release see: http://blog.quicklisp.org/2011/08/going-back-in-dist-time.html.